# Can we use OR operator in Helm yaml files

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Can I do something like this in Helm yamls :

```
{{- if eq .Values.isCar true }} OR {{- if eq .Values.isBus true }}
# do something
{{- end }}
```

I understand that we can do a single if check. But how would I check for multiple conditions? Are there some operators equivalent to OR and AND?

Answer (score 230, accepted):

As indicated in the [Helm documentation on operators](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/functions_and_pipelines/#operators-are-functions):

> For templates, the operators (`eq`, `ne`, `lt`, `gt`, `and`, `or` and so on) are all implemented as functions. In pipelines, operations can be grouped with parentheses (`(`, and `)`).

It means you could use

```yaml
    {{- if or (eq .Values.isCar true) (eq .Values.isBus true) }}
```

Furthermore, as noted in the [if/else structure](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures/#ifelse):

> A pipeline is evaluated as false if the value is:
>
> - a boolean false
> - a numeric zero
> - an empty string
> - a nil (empty or null)
> - an empty collection (map, slice, tuple, dict, array)
>
> Under all other conditions, the condition is true.

If your properties (`isCar` and `isBus`) are booleans, you can then skip the equal check:

```yaml
    {{- if or .Values.isCar .Values.isBus }}
```

Comment: direct links have shifted to:

https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/functions_and_pipelines/#operators-are-functions

https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures/#ifelse

Comment: I could not find this in the official documentation. Would be a useful addition!

Comment: What about conditions with more than 2 arguments? 
EX-{{-if and (a) (b) (c) }} 
EX2-{{-if eq (a) (b) (c) }}
QUESTION: Is it checking equality for all members ?

Comment: for the first example you gave `if or (eq a b) (eq c d)` are the parens required or optional? seems like they are required IMO. but i'm no expert.

Comment: Such a bad syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Note that `or` can also be used instead of `default` like this:

```
{{ or .Values.someSetting "default_value" }}
```

This would render to `.Values.someSetting` if it is set or to
`"default_value"` otherwise.

Comment: thanks it was helpful...!

Comment: This feels like a terrible syntax, especially when use with booleans... just got my brain explode when seeing `{{ or .Values.someSetting "true" }}` (which to me reads as if always resulting to `true`....) in some chart ... use `default` (or maybe `coalesce`) for falling back to a default value ... semantics matter

Comment: @Julien I would not recommed this syntax to anyone. It is indeed hard to understand and read. I added this answer here for completeness.